# Microsoft Excel :: Checkbox Macro

Tags: excel, checkbox, excel-2010

I want it so that when I check the box for item 1, text appears next to it. I've written a simple macro for that already. The issue is, that I want the text to disappear when the box is unchecked. I have it so that when you check the box the text appears. If you uncheck the box, the text *does not* disappear, and I want it to. [image]
So basically, all I want it to do is to have text appear when I check the box, and the text disappear when I uncheck it. How can I do this.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
'
' CheckBox1_Click Macro
'

'
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Puppy Tears"
Range("E3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Tuna"
Range("E4").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you show what code you have already?

Comment: I added it the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of your checkbox and use an `if` statement to toggle on/off.

If you have use a "Form Control" Checkbox you can use the following example:

```
Sub Checkbox1_Click()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

If Sheet.Shapes("Check box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
    ' checkbox is checked
Else
    ' checkbox is not checked
End If
End Sub
```

Manually changing the names of shapes is (i think, never really looked into it) fairly tricky but you can use the following macro(s) to add checkboxes, and it includes a macro to handle all the events for your checkboxes

```
' this code should be added in a new module (menu->insert->module)

Sub AddCheck()
' this sub will add a new checkbox to sheet1 in the active cell. you specify the name, and the name will be duplicated in the caption
Dim Name As String: Name = InputBox("Shape Name")
Dim Shape As Shape
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim PTop As Integer
Dim PLeft As Integer

PTop = ActiveCell.Top
PLeft = ActiveCell.Left

Set Shape = Sheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlCheckBox, PLeft, PTop, 100, 10)

Shape.Name = Name
Shape.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = Name
Shape.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
Shape.OnAction = "Checkbox_Click"

End Sub

Sub Checkbox_Click()
' this is a generic function that will be fired by all checkboxes added using the above macro

Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' copy and edit the following if statement for all checkboxes
If Sheet.Shapes("Check1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
    ' its checked
Else
    ' its not checked
End If

End Sub
```

If you've used an "ActiveX Control", then I cant really help as Excel wont let me add one at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
    Do While CheckBox1.Value = True And i < 3
        Range("D1").Value = "Puppy tears"
        Range("D2").Value = "Tuna"
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Do While CheckBox1 = False And i < 3
        Range("D1").Value = ""
        Range("D2").Value = ""
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

I guess this will help you (You should use an ActiveX Control, otherwise it will not go into the first loop.)